# How do I install Clang Version 3 in 10.10?

Tags: installation, programming, compiling, install-from-source, compiler

How would I go about installing version 3 of Clang/LLVM in Ubuntu 10.10? Ubuntu 10.10 installs version 2.8 by default. Version 3 has more extensive/up to date support for C++ and possibly C (I am not totally sure about C). I know that I could possibly compile from source but was wondering if there is a ppa or other method to avoid compiling it from source.

If I compile from source do I have to tell it where to find the std c library etc. or is that automatically done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found a PPA for maverick - you will need a later version of ubuntu to get v3.

However, to compile is very straightforward.  [Clang themselves](http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html) have the instructions well written.  A few pointers:

You will need the following packages to be installed before you compile

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential subversion
```

Start at the second instruction "2. Checkout LLVM"

At step 4 there is a mistake - it should read `cd ../projects`

I didnt need to specify my C/C++ headers - `configure` worked this out by itself.

Word of warning - it takes hours to compile - best to leave this as an overnight job!

Comment: Thanks. Once compiled should I checkisntall it or leave it as is. I am building it as we speak in a build folder in /usr/local/src/build. Should I leave it there or move it to /usr/local/bin. I don't think /usr/local/src is in my path but I can easily add it to my path.

Comment: personally I would just have build it in my local home folder.  The choice is yours where the folder locations will be - my personal opinion - `make install` will install in the default folders - it makes it easier if you build and install a newer version in the future - if you need to adjust your path if required.

Comment: I was just following tradition in using /usr/local/ for locally installed software besides /usr/local/bin is already in the automatically generated path.